# Filtro en Laravel para trabajos no realizados, incompletos o completados

Tags: laravel, eloquent, filtro, scope

he estado buscando hace tiempo una solución a este problema pero no he encontrado nada que pueda adaptar.

Existen dos tablas `ordensiembras` y `siembras`, una orden puede tener varias siembras.

[image: Tablas]

El modelo de Ordensiembras:

```
    public function sembrado() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Siembra');

    }
```

Necesito generar un scope con valores 1 si no se ha ejecutado (`cantReal==0`) 2 si está completado (la suma de `cantReal==cantOrden`) y 3 si está incompleta (`cantReal<cantOrden`)

```
    public function scopeCompletado($query, $fcompletado)
    {
    if($fcompletado==1)
        return $query->where('???????');
    if($fcompletado==2)
        return $query->where('???????');
    if($fcompletado==3)
        return $query->where('???????');
    }
```

Podría revisar la suma de `siembras.canReal` en la vista y no mostrar los registros que no cumplan con el criterio, pero en este caso no funciona la paginación.

Comment: podrías agregar el código de `$query`?

Comment: Claro:         $ordenes=OrdenSiembra::orderBy('semana',"DESC")    
        ->fcliente($fcliente)
        ->fsemana($fsemana)
        ->fannio($fannio)
        ->fvariedad($fvariedad)
        ->completado($fcompletado)
        ->paginate(10);

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si en vez de intentar de reutilizar tanto vas por un lado un poco mas logico y sano, create 3 scope.

```
public function scopeSinEjecutar($query)
{
    return $query->where($this->cantReal, 0);
}
```

Ahora, para completado y sin completar yo trabajaría con la misma relación colocando un condicional, algo bastante util de conocer, quedando asi.

```
public function completado() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Siembra')->where('catReal', '=', $this->cantOrden);
}


public function scopeCompletado($query)
{
    return $query->has('completado');
}


public function scopeSinCompletar($query)
{
    return $query->has('noCompletado');
}
```

//Con tener completado ya te imaginaras como se hace no completado.

Claro, puedes combinar eso y crear una sola función, supongo que es valido, pero, realmente vale la pena?